# Display row data of all columns upon selecting row or checkbox in MUI datatable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

I have a MUI datatable. The properties are defined as follows

```
data={serialsList || []}
            columns={columns}
            options={{
              ...muiDataTableCommonOptions(),
              download: false,
              expandableRowsOnClick: false,
              search: false,
              page: currentPage,
              rowsPerPage: numberOfRows,
              count: serialsTotalCounts,
              selectableRows: this.state.cancelShipFlag ? 'multiple' : 'none',
              selectableRowsHeader: this.state.cancelShipFlag ? true : false,
              selectToolbarPlacement: 'none',
              onRowSelectionChange(currentRowsSelected, allRowsSelected, rowsSelected?) {
                console.log(currentRowsSelected, allRowsSelected, rowsSelected);
              },
              //selectableRowsHideCheckboxes: this.state.cancelShipFlag ? true : false,
              onRowClick: (rowData, rowMeta) => console.log('onRowsSelect.', rowData, rowMeta),
```

I want to display the entire row contents as a Json or string if I select a particular row or a checkbox in that row. How do I do this?
I have read that we can use

```
getSelectedRows: () => Map<GridRowId, GridRowModel>
```

But i am not sure how to use it. Can someone guide me in this?
I have also seen this link for reference but not sure if it will work

[Sandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/66424752get-row-item-on-checkbox-selection-in-react-material-ui-data-grid-wp4vl?file=/demo.tsx:464-649)

Answer (score 0):

According by your example

```
// State for selected rows
const [selectedRows, setSelectedRows] = useState([]);

// Save selected rows to state
onRowSelectionChange: (currentSelect, allSelected) => {           
  setSelectedRows(allSelected);  
}

// return as a JSON
<pre style={{ fontSize: 10 }}>
  {JSON.stringify(selectedRows, null, 4)}
</pre>
```

Comment: My table is defined inside a class. Where do I define the hook so that the onRowSelectionChange can access it? Should I use setState instead? Can you tell the syntax in that case?

Comment: if you are using class syntax, replace hook to this.setState/this.state https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: This just returns the row index right? I want the data from the other columns as well. How do I get that?
For example, onRowClick: (rowData) returns the data from all the columns in that row. i want something similar but when we click the checkbox instead